# Show image when woocommerce product has attribute or has attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I have a product catalog on wordpress + woocommerce and I want to make on product page this:

1) If the product has the attribute "Radio" - then need to show picture # 1, if the attribute "Radio" is not - then show picture # 2

2) If the product has the attribute "Color" with the value "Black", then need to show picture # 1, if not, then show picture # 2

3) If the product has the attribute "Material" or "Case", and one of them or both have the value "Leather" - then need to show picture # 1. If both attributes do not have this value, then show picture # 2

I do not know php to solve this problem. Hope the community helps me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Forst you will get `wc_get_products();` then an if condition would be enough to deal with rest of your conditions `$product->get_attributes();`